# Casting to a type held in a variable

Tags: swift, casting

I am attempting to cast a variable to a different type that is held in a variable or is the return type of a function. Here is the idea:

```
let i = 1 as type(of: 3.14)
```

But when I do this, I get a couple of errors:

- Use of undeclared type 'type'
- Consecutive statements on a line must be separated by ';' (This inserts a semi-colon between `type` and `(of: 3.14)`)

And a warning:

- Expression of type `(of: Double)` is unused

How to I cast a value to a type that is held in a variable?

Comment: Your example won't work anyway. It's impossible to cast numeric types to each other.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Swift (currently) requires the Type assignment at compile time. You can do some things *like* this, but you will need to write a converter for each type combination you want to use, e.g:

```
func convertType(from item: Int) -> Float {
    return Float(item)
}

var item: Float = convertType(from: 1)
```

I would caution going down this road and try and get used to Swift's way of doing things. If you absolutely need it you should be able to use some generic functions with a protocol like `FloatConvertable` to handle this more simply.

Answer (score 1):

The Swift grammar doesn't allow for these types of expressions. The expression after `as` must be the name of a type, ie. `1 as Double` (though, as vadian points out, you can't cast numeric types to each other, so a better example would be `mySubClassObject as MySuperClass`). Swift is a strongly typed language, which means it needs to know the types of all variables at compile time.